# Card Carousel swipe with details in flutter

Tags: animation, flutter, dart, slider, carousel

I want to create a stack of images with a carousel effect, details of the image will be displayed below in a different container. While swiping an image from the stack, details will be changed with the image.

Already done with the image carousel part and swiping.

```
CarouselSlider(
  viewportFraction: 0.7,
  aspectRatio: 1,
  autoPlay: true,
  enlargeCenterPage: true,
  items: carouselList.map(
    (image) {
      return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10),
          ),
          image:
              DecorationImage(image: AssetImage(image), fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
      );
    },
  ).toList(),
);
```

How to change the details of the image while swiping an image from the stack?
Want to achieve a slider like the below image.

[image]

Comment: Were you able to achieve this?

Comment: did you find it finally or not?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this in the package where you can create your own dynamic tree:

```
CarouselSlider.builder(
   itemCount: 15,
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex) =>
        Container(
            child: Text(itemIndex.toString()),
        ),
   )
```

your carouselList will be list of class object where you have the title,release_date , ratings and the image. passing the list to the builder will render the every object up to that length.